# mahout - seq2sparse not creating vectors

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout

I have twitter data (usernames and their tweets) which I am trying to cluster. The text file is 151.7 MB in size.

- I converted the raw txt text data to a mahout sequence file.
- I inspected this sequence file, it's full of data. It's also 151.7 MB.
- I tried to convert the sequence file to sparse vectors.

At this point something has clearly gone wrong. It claims success, but it only creates vector files that are bytes in size. My TFIDF vector file is only 90 bytes, which is obviously wrong when the original txt file and the sequence file are both 151 MB.

What confuses me most is that I can't see what's so different between the data I have and the reuters dataset which is used in the clustering example in 'Mahout in Action'. They're both just text.

Here are the exact commands I used:

--- Turned raw text txt file into a mahout sequence file. I've also checked the sequence file using seqdumper, it's full of username/tweet data. ---

```
 sudo /opt/mahout/bin/mahout seqdirectory -c UTF-8 -i /home/efx/Desktop/tweetQueryOutput.txt -o /home/efx/Desktop/allNYCdataseqfiles
```

(Inspect the sequence file, it's full of username/tweet data)

```
 sudo /opt/mahout/bin/mahout seqdumper -i /home/efx/Desktop/allNYCdataseqfiles/chunk-0 -o /home/efx/Desktop/allNYCdataseqfiles/sequenceDumperOutput
```

--- Then tried to convert the sequence file to sparse vectors. ---

```
 sudo /opt/mahout/bin/mahout seq2sparse -o /home/efx/Desktop/allNYC_DataVectors -i /home/efx/Desktop/allNYCdataseqfiles/ -seq
```

Comment: Which version of Mahout are you using?

Comment: I am using mahout version 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Under Mahout 0.8+cdh5.0.2, you have to do the following :

```
sudo /opt/mahout/bin/mahout seq2sparse 
-o /home/efx/Desktop/allNYC_DataVectors 
-i /home/efx/Desktop/allNYCdataseqfiles/
-seq
--maxDFPercent 100
```

The `--maDFPercent` options represents the max percentage of docs for the DF. It can be used to remove really high frequency terms. By default the value is 99. But if you use `--maxDFSigma` also, it will override this value.

This works fine for me but I'm not sure about the 0.7 version of Mahout.